# WCF method does not return

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a curious problem with a WCF service I've not been able to solve.
When I call a specific method on my service, it simply does not return to the client until the binding times out, although it already has returned on the server and a return message has been sent to the client.

I'm using `ChannelFactory<T>` on the client side, and shared interfaces that are defined like so:

```
[ServiceContract]
interface IService {
    [OperationContract] bool Upload(Guid id, string name, byte[] data);
    [OperationContract] bool Unlock(Guid id);
}

[ServiceContract(Name = "IService")]
interface IServiceAsync : IService {
    [OperationContract] Task<bool> UploadAsync(Guid id, string name, byte[] data);
    [OperationContract] Task<bool> UnlockAsync(Guid id);
}
```

The `IService` interface is implemented by the server class, the `IServiceAsync` interface is only used on the client (and works automagically).
The server is implemented in a standalone console application using `ServiceHost`, the server class looks like this:

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = Single, ConcurrencyMode = Multiple)]
static class Server : IService {
    public bool Upload(Guid id, string name, byte[] data) { ... }
    public bool Unlock(Guid id) { ... }
}
```

On the client side, I create a channel using a `ChannelFactory<T>` like this:

```
static IServiceAsync GetService() {
    EndpointAddress endpoint = new EndpointAddress(/* some Uri */);
    NetTcpBinding binding = /* NetTcpBinding without security */;

    ChannelFactory<IServiceAsync> factory =
            new ChannelFactory<IServiceAsync>(binding, endpoint);
    factory.Open();
    IServiceAsync proxy = factory.CreateChannel();
    ((IServiceChannel)proxy).Open();
    return proxy;
}
```

In my scenario, I then upload some files to the server, an operation that can be canceled by the user at any time. The code for the upload looks something like this:

```
static async void UseService(IServiceAsync proxy) {
    try {
        byte[] buffer;
        do {
            cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            buffer = GetBytes();
            bool uploaded = await proxy.UploadAsync(id, name, buffer);
        } while(buffer.Length > 0);
        ((IClientChannel)proxy).Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        try {
            proxy.Unlock(id);
        }
        catch {
            // Connection may have failed
        }
        throw;
    }
}
```

Now when the upload finishes everything works fine, but when the upload is canceled, and `cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()` throws an exception, I want to unlock the server.
So I call `proxy.Unlock(id)`, which gets called on the server, returns there (confirmed by writing to the console immediately before `return true;` on the server), but does not return on the client side until the binding times out.

I looked at the network traffic once and confirmed that there is actually a return message being sent to the client. (I don't actually know whether `proxy.Unlock(id)` just returns or throws a `CommunicationException`, i suspect the second one.)

TL;DR: A WCF method does not return on the client side although it already returned on the server side, other methods work fine.

So, in case you're still here after that wall of text: what is wrong here?
How can I debug or solve this?
If you need any more information please let me know.

#### Update:

Thanks to Daniel's comment I did some tracing and managed to reproduce the problem on a small scale.

The problem only seems to happen when `ConfigureAwait(false)` is used when awaiting async WCF methods, an exception is thrown, and there is no context switch before the next call to a WCF method. I uploaded a small [test project](https://github.com/PeterFeicht/AsyncWcfTest) on GitHub.

Could this be a bug in the automagically implemented async methods in the WCF proxy?

Comment: What is the purpose of your empty `try/catch` block? It does nothing useful.

Comment: Do you mean the one that contains `proxy.Unlock(id)`? That's because the connection may have failed so `proxy.Unlock(id)` will throw an exception.

Comment: but you wouldn't know - theres nothing in the catch

Comment: and what that proxy.Unlock does on server?

Comment: Well, I don't really need to know since I can't do anything about it anyway (aside from creating a new connection, but that's not necessary).

Comment: The server manages PCs that can be locked, accept uploads and do stuff with the files. In case the user cancels an upload, I want to release the particular PC that was locked before so it can be used by other clients.

Comment: Turn on WCF tracing, it can help you a lot! https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Daniel Thanks for the tracing tip! I spent the last few hours making sense of some traces, however I still don't really know what's going on. I suspect it's some kind of deadlock inside of WCF, the traces show that the server does indeed send the message but it's never processed on the client side. I will try and edit this into the question tomorrow.